# Responsive Web Design - Can't remove the white space and horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, media-queries

I new in reponsive web design and finding it really hard to sort out the problem.

I started with iphone 4 screen size and used the following media query:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait)
```

And also used the following viewport in the header section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Though i set the body and html width to 320px and the `overflow-x: hidden;`
It still shows the white empty space on the right which causes the horizontal scroll to appear.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait){

    body, html{width:320px; overflow-x: hidden;}
    .navlogo{position: absolute; left: 2px; top: 0;}
    #globalheader{width:320px !important; margin:0; padding:0; margin-right:0;}
    #globalheader .wrap{width:320px;}
    #globalnavholder{left:28px;} 
    #globalheader .navlogo{float:left;}
    #globalheader .wrap{width:320px;}
    #globalnav li{display:block; float:none; width:100%; }
    .home-body-main{ width:360px; overflow:hidden; margin: 0 auto; }

    .canvas-home{ width:320px; overflow-x:hidden; height:150px; display:none;} 

    .after-canvas-panel{width:320px !important; margin: 0 auto; margin-left:0; display: block; padding-bottom:100px;}
    .home-body-paragraph{width:320px; margin: 0 auto; margin-left:0;}
    #footer .wrap{width:320px;}
}
```

Comment: Use [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: Have you tried adding this to your css: `@viewport { width:device-width;}`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css: `@viewport { width:device-width;}`

Answer (score 0):

One of the main goals with responsive is getting away from "fixed widths", especially if they're equal to or close to the device width.  So I would change everything that has

```
{ width: 320px; }
```

to something like

```
{ width: 100%; }
```

And you may want a max-width on your larger media queries or basic CSS.  You may want that around 960px or 1000px for larger screens, depending upon your needs.  And if you're using width of 100% (for small screens especially) make sure you don't have padding... that got me a few times.